# How to convert an ACCDB to an MDB in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an .ACCDB database in Access 2010. I need to convert it to an .MDB file, but I am not able to do this.

Is it possible to do this in Access 2010? If so, please provide the necessary steps.

Answer (score 11):

Open the .accdb file in Access. On the "File" tab of the ribbon, choose "Save & Publish", select the type of .mdb file you want to create (Access 2000 or Access 2002-2003) and click the "Save As" button.

[image: SavePublish.png]

Answer (score 0):

When a database contains incorrectly linked table, like linking to tables in not existing files, conversion does not occur, without any message box with reason, silently. At least in Access 2016. But after deletion or repairing such tables the file is converted.

Answer (score 0):

If the database contains any features that prevent you from saving it as an .mdb file, Access displays a message and prevents you from continuing!